# Is it possible to open MS Teams "deep link for chat" without users?

Tags: microsoft-teams

To share Content with MS Teams users we can use this "deep link for chat" from the [MS Teams documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links):

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=joe@contoso.com,bob@contoso.com&topicName=Prep%20For%20Meeting%20Tomorrow&message=Hi%20folks%2C%20kicking%20off%20a%20chat%20about%20our%20meeting%20tomorrow
```

But if we need to open a MS Teams Chat without users, it is only working on Android and iOS. For example this link:

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?topicName=Prep%20For%20Meeting%20Tomorrow&message=Hi%20folks%2C%20kicking%20off%20a%20chat%20about%20our%20meeting%20tomorrow
```

is not working on Microsoft Windows. MS Teams open, but nothing happens.

The same link works fine on an android phone with MS Teams installed. The App starts, and the message shows at the bottom and on the top users can be selected.

I played around with the link and added some random characters for the parameter "users" -> MS Teams starts, but the message from the parameter "message" is not showing up in the text input field.

We need to open MS Teams without users, because we don't know which users from MS-Teams the user from our system want to select.

So is it possible to open MS Teams "deep link for chat" without users?

Answer (score 1):

This item remains on the backlog in Teams UserVoice,
Microsoft will always focus on customer’s feedback and experience, some new features would be added to the services based on customers' feedback in the future, we also recommend you give your new idea in Teams [UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com).

Comment: I followed your advice and added a new UserVoice to Teams.